# Increasing the print depth in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to get SML/NJ to print out a result at the top level without
putting # signs everywhere.

According to some old docs (and a post to this newsgroup on 2001), it
should be possible to use `Compiler.Control.Print.printDepth`

However, on SML/NJ version 110.7, this just gives an error:

```
- Compiler.Control.Print.printDepth := 100;
stdIn:1.1-30.8 Error: unbound structure: Control in path Compiler.Control.Print.printDepth
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might wan't to be more precise in the future. You could for example give some sample output and a link to where you found the above.

If I understand your problem correct, then the last line below is your problem? (code snippet

```
- datatype tree = leaf | node of int * tree * tree;
datatype tree = leaf | node of int * tree * tree 

- val t = node (1, node (2, node (3, leaf, leaf), leaf), leaf);
val t = node (1,node (2,node #,leaf),leaf) : tree
```

Then the [Control.Print](http://www.smlnj.org//doc/Compiler/pages/printcontrol.html#PRINTCONTROL:SIG:SPEC) structure is what you are looking for. So just drop the  `Compiler` part and use

```
Control.Print.printDepth := 100;
```

Do note that this is SML/NJ specific and not ml-yacc as such.